# Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? in @Mui Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have this component

```
 <Controller
    control={control}
    {...register("DOB", {})}
    render={({ field }) => (
       <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
          <DatePicker
             value={
               field.value ? field.value : dayjs(defaultvalues.DOB)
             }
             onChange={(val) => {
               field.onChange(val);
             }}
             id="DOB"
             format="YYYY-MM-DD"
             label={t("Date of Bearth")}
           />
        </LocalizationProvider>
     )}
   />
```

It works but in conmsole I have this warnig. How to get rid of it?

Comment: could you add the entire component ?

Comment: Yes, I need, becouse DatePicker need that in order to changing value, set default values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your component it is missing to forward the ref that is in field

```
 <Controller
   control={control}
   {...register("DOB", {})}
   render={({ field }) => (
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
         <DatePicker
            inputRef={field.ref}  <<---------
            value={
              field.value ? field.value : dayjs(defaultvalues.DOB)
            }
            onChange={(val) => {
              field.onChange(val);
            }}
            id="DOB"
            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
            label={t("Date of Bearth")}
          />
       </LocalizationProvider>
    )}
  />
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @sadasdadssad could you provide entire component code or a POC with your problem?
you can use stackblitz, codepen, etc for this